# Use attributes with `auto` return value in function declaration

Tags: d

```
struct A {
    auto f(); // fine
    const(int) g() const; // fine
    const(auto) h() const; // *death*
    inout(auto) h() inout; // *death*
    ...(auto) h() ...; // etc. etc.
}
```

I don't believe this needs much explanation. How do I get the intended effect of the `h()` declarations in D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you use `auto`  by itself as the return type, and in the function body, you return a value with the appropriate constness qualifier. You can use the `cast(const) value` syntax to add a const qualifier to a value.